# Automated testing for Windows desktop

Tags: automated-testing, java, test-automation-framework, windows

I am looking for a free tool to create automated test scripts for a Java-Swing application. I found Sikuli, but it wasn't updated years ago and seems to be an unstable solution. Winium looks obsolete too, it wasn't developed in the last few years as can be seen in their GitHub repository.

Comment: What Java GUI technology? JavaFX, Swing, AWT, SWT, … ?

Comment: @beatngu13 : It is a Swing application, but I am interested in multi-purpose frameworks too.

Comment: Multi-purpose means less optimization and less focus on the single task I need to solve *right now*. Sometimes the compromise is worth the price, but often it is not. Vendors of IT technology do have inherent interest to design their technology in a way **not compatible with other vendors** so it is harder to switch to competitors: it is called [Vendor lock-in](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vendor_lock-in) and some companies (Microsoft, Oracle) are famous for using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/) is deprecated as mentioned on [GitHub](https://github.com/sikuli/sikuli):

> A new version of Sikuli(X) is available since 2013
>   as a follow up development

[SikuliX](http://sikulix.com/) seems pretty active when you look at their [GitHub](https://github.com/RaiMan/SikuliX2). Haven't worked with SikuliX myself, but they say they use [OpenCV](https://opencv.org/) (i.e. computer vision) to interact with anything on the screen. Seems like a reasonable approach when you're interested in a tool that can do more than Swing.

[Winium](https://github.com/2gis/Winium) won't help you because it only supports applications that are based on either WinForms or WPF.

Personally, I prefer native solutions. I've never been a friend of (pure) computer vision-based tools because usually you get faster and more stable tests when you have a tool that knows the underlying GUI technology (like Selenium or Appium). When it comes to Swing and you're looking for a free solution, [AssertJ Swing](https://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-swing.html) is probably one of the best open source libraries. It's a fork of [FEST](https://code.google.com/archive/p/fest/) and has the following features:

> - [Simulation of user interaction](https://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-swing-input.html) with a GUI (e.g. drag 'n drop)
> - Reliable [GUI component lookup](https://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-swing-lookup.html) (by type, by name or custom search criteria)
> - Support for all Swing components included in the JDK
> - Compact and powerful API for creation and maintenance of functional GUI tests
> - Supports [Applet testing](https://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-swing-launch.html#applets)
> - Ability to embed [screenshots of failed GUI tests](https://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-swing-troubleshooting-screenshots.html) in HTML test reports
> - Can be used with either [TestNG](http://testng.org/) or [JUnit](http://junit.org/)
> - Supports [testing violations](https://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-swing-edt.html#testing-violations) of Swing's threading rules
> - Can be used with [JIDE Software](http://www.jidesoft.com/) (since 1.1.0)

Moreover, it's actively maintained, offers a comprehensive documentation, supports Java 8, and [AssertJ](https://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/index.html) itself has some neat assertions.

Answer (score 1):

For automating a window based application try **WinAppDriver**. A UI test automation tool for Window based applications. (https://github.com/Microsoft/WinAppDriver). It includes Appium to test the UI of a Window based application.

Features :

1. Support Appium
2. Supports API requests
3. Supported locators to find the UI elements

Comment: It supports only Windows 10.